# multilevel logistic panel regression with glmer in R

Tags: logistic, lme4-nlme, multilevel-analysis

My dataset (long format) contains of data collected in 4 studies. Although the variables in the studies were identical, I want to account for the heterogeneity of the population between these studies and thus treat "study" as a random effect.

In the study, participants made 25 binary choices (0/1). I want to test, whether attitudes and trait self-control predict making choice 1.

Thus, my logistic regression model should account for the fact that one subject made 25 decisions and that the subjects were nested within one study.

I would suggest the following: 
model <-glmer(depvar ~ attitude + selfcontrol + (1 | subject) + (1 | study), data = df, family = binomial("logit"))

Is that correct? Thank you for any advice!

Comment: Please register &/or merge your accounts (you can find information on how to do 
this in the **My Account** section of our [help]), then you will be able to 
edit & comment on your own question.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the site anwyy! Your model looks like it will give you exactly what you want. The big question is whether it makes sense to have a random intercept with just four levels. This is something that is certainly doable within maximum likelihood estimation, and is especially viable if using a Bayesian approach where you put some "restrictions" on the shape and variance of the random intercept through your prior specification. Worst case scenario is that if you use `glmer` with that small number of levels for year, the random intercepts are likely to have a lot of uncertainty (expressed as standard errors of the Empirical Bayes predictions).

The other option to consider is the so-called "no pooling" approach, which is to add study as a categorical predictor to the fixed effects part of the model. This has the effect of turning the coefficients on attitude and self-control into within-study estimates if these vary within studies.

For example, "within a study, on average, the log odds of the dependent variable increases/decreases by XX with a 1 unit increase on self-control."