# xtmelogit vs. glmer different results

Tags: logistic, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, stata

My dataset (long format) contains of data collected in 4 studies. Although the variables in the studies were identical, I want to account for the substantial heterogeneity of the populations between these studies and thus treat "study" as a random effect.
In each study, participants were randomly presented with 25 binary choices (0/1). 
I want to test whether attitudes and trait self-control predict making choice 1.

Thus, my logistic regression model should account for the fact that each subject made 25 decisions and that the subjects were nested within one study.

To test this, I used R:

```
model <-glmer(
  depvar ~ attitude + selfcontrol + (1 | study/subject),
  data = df,
  family = binomial("logit")
)
```

and I tried the same with stata. After having defined the panel with xtset, I tried:

```
xtmelogit depvar attitude selfcontrol || study:
```

The coefficients are extremely different (and thus also the plots differ)! Is one of the models wrongly defined?
Even if I try to change things like laplace approximation, the results just does not even get close to similar.

Answer (score 1):

Those are different models. In the case of `lmer`, you are estimating a 3-level model of decisions nested within subject within study. By the way this is different than the syntax you described in your [other post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/451666/multilevel-logistic-panel-regression-with-glmer-in-r). In that post, you treated study as a non-nested random intercept. I'm not sure why you have changed it, but that is your choice.

In comparison, the model you estimated with `xtmelogit` in Stata is a 2-level model that depends on which variables you mentioned when you `xtset` the data. If you wanted to run a comparable model with Stata, you should use `melogit`, specifying the random effects similarly as you did in `lmer`. For example, for a three-level model, the random effects structure in `meologit` would be `|| study: || subject:`.

Comment: Thank you very much again for your answer!

I changed it because I thought that (1 | study/subject) would be more suitable for my data, as I try to tell the model that subjects were nested within study - but I may be totally wrong. 
How would you do it?

Reg. Stata: I did xtset subject decisionnumber. 

Which model would you chose given the data structure I described? 
Wouldn't a 3-level model be correct (~25 decisions nested within one person, who themselves are nested within one study)?

Your help means a lot to me, thank you very much!! :-)

Comment: I would probably treat study as a fixed effect predictor rather than a random effect. You only have 3 studies, right? In Stata, that would mean adding it as `i.study` to your list of predictors. If you do that, then you can use `xtlogit` given that you only have two levels - observations within subject and you used `xtset` to define the cluster variable (subject).

Comment: I have 4 studies (Mturk with n=200, Mturk with n=600, Prolific with n=600 and student sample with n = 70) and the means/variance of self-control and attitudes as well as their effects on the behavior varies a lot between them. 

Now I am confused in what whay the stata commands are different from each other: 

xtmelogit depvar attitude selfcontrol || study: (with subject defined as cluster var)
and
melogit depvar attitude selfcontrol || study: || subject

in R this would be the exact same code, no?

Thank you, I promise this will be my last question :-)

Comment: What version of Stata are you using? If a newer 14+, you should be using `melogit`, *not* `xtmelogit`. Either way, you need to define the random effects structure irrespective of what you did with `xtset`. So I would propose the following model: `melogit DV IV1 IV2 i.study || subject:` In `glmer`: `glmer(DV ~ IV1 + IV2 + as.factor(study) + (1|subject)`.