# xtmelogit vs. melogit

Tags: mixed-model, stata, multilevel-analysis

I have already asked some related questions, but I am still unsure about the following Stata commands. 
Could anyone tell me how these commands/models are different from each other?

```
xtset subject decisionnumber
xtmelogit depvar iv1##iv2 || study:

melogit depvar iv1##iv2 || study: || subject:
```

Answer (score 4):

In Stata, `xtset` is used when you want to use the `xt` suite of commands and the purpose of `xtset` is to tell Stata what your panel ID and time variables are. Note that `xtset` is to be used in conjunction with a host of `xt` models, including `xtreg`, `xtlogit`, and `xtpoisson` but ***not*** `xtmelogit`. See the very clear documentation in Stata's [xt manual](https://www.stata.com/manuals14/xtxt.pdf).

```
xtmelogit depvar iv1##iv2 || study:
```

In this case, you are using `xtmelogit`, which is not the most up-to-date version of this command in Stata, and also, confusingly, does not connect with `xtset`. Thus, the `xtmelogit` command you are using assumes that there is only 1 random intercept of interest - study. That is not what you want.

Instead, you ***should*** use

```
melogit depvar iv1##iv2 || study: || subject:
```

which appropriately indicates your random effects structure as being 3-level, observations nested within subjects nested within study. As I mentioned in a previous [response](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/451749/xtmelogit-vs-glmer-different-results) to you, with only 4 studies, it is questionable whether you want to study include this as a random intercept. You could easily include it as a fixed intercept and would not have to make the same distributional assumptions as you do by including it as a random effect:

```
melogit depvar iv1##iv2 i.study || subject:
```

Ultimately, it is  up to you which way you want to go with study.

Comment: thank you so much, this has helped a lot!! 
I just compared the two models 
model_1<-glmer(dec ~ 1 + z_nep + z_selfcontrol + z_nep*z_selfcontrol + (1 | study/subject), data = pooled.cq1, family = binomial("logit"))

model_2<-glmer(dec ~ 1 + z_nep + z_selfcontrol + z_nep*z_selfcontrol + factor(study) + (1 | study), data = pooled.cq1, family = binomial("logit"))

using anova, and their difference is not significant. So you were very right, the model with study as fixed effects would be sufficient. Thanks again, I have learned a lot with you help!

Comment: Glad to be of help!

Comment: +1 very nice answer, Erik